# Dockerfile for minimum image size on R-base

Tags: r, docker, build, dockerfile, size

I'm trying to minimize the size of my docker image. It's on R-Base from the rocker project. It needs to be as small as possible, since it is used as a container instance in a cloud based workflow.

The image needs some extra packages (`dplyr`, `pdftools`, `stringr` and `AzureStor`). Some are available as binary, but `AzureStor` I could not find as such.

I already used some recommended commands to minimize size. What can I do more? Please read the docker file below. A few options I'm considering now:

- Can I save space using 'no cache'? How do I 'implement' this?
- Is there a binary version for a R package like `AzureStor`? I can't find it.
- Are there any other build commands or dockerfile lines I can use to reduce any excess size?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my current dockerfile

```
    FROM rocker/r-base:latest
## install binary, build and dependend packages from single run command

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends --purge
r-cran-pdftools \
r-cran-dplyr \
r-cran-stringr \
libxml2-dev \
libssl-dev && \

## install non-binary packages (from the same run command)

echo "r <- getOption('repos');r['CRAN'] <- 'http://cran.us.r-project.org'; options(repos = r);" > ~/.Rprofile && \
Rscript -e "install.packages(c('AzureStor'))" && \

mkdir -p /scripts \

## remove and clean what we can (still the same run command)
apt-get autoclean && \
apt-get -y autoremove libssl-dev && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

## copy code
COPY script / script

## Set workdir
WORKDIR /scripts

## command line for autorunning the entire rscript
CMD [ "Rscript", "runscript.R"]
```

Right now, the size is around 800 mb. Hoping to get this down.

Comment: try switching dplyr for data.table and see the effect on image size

Comment: I'll try that. Too bad I'm not that familiar with data.table as with dplyr. I'll get back with the results in image size difference. Thnx!

Comment: The data.table package 'saves' 8mb image size compared to an image with the dplyr-package. Not much, but all bits help!

Comment: yea but probably not worth the extra effort of learning a new syntax :)

Comment: You could build `AzureStor` using a multi-stage build: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: Thnx @AEF. I experimented with multi-stage builds, but I find it difficult to get the right syntax in de dockerfile to fully take advantage of the multi-stage advantages. Could you give me an example of how you would apply the multi-stage syntax to install the AzureStor package?

Comment: Just start with the same R base image and install the package like in your dockerfile. Then copy the package folder to your actual image. (I think its located in /usr/local/lib/R/site-library)

Comment: Ok, so use a command in stage 2 to copy the library from the 1ste stage image? Like: COPY /usr/local/lib/R/site-library //usr/local/lib/R/site-library ?

Comment: You might want to check [r-minimal](https://github.com/r-hub/r-minimal). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748746/how-can-i-minimize-the-size-of-the-installation-of-a-r-package) is also related.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and references @ismirsehregal