# How can I minimize the size of the installation of a R package

Tags: r, r-package

At my workplace we are installing a lot of libraries for different versions of R. Size required is quickly going up. What can I do to minimise each installation as much as possible?
I know about --no-docs and I require --with-keep.source

**EDIT:** Here is a quick study on my setup

I copied my library in `/tmp/library`

```
library(fs)                                                                             
library(data.table)                                                                     
library(stringr)
lib_dir <- "/tmp/library"                                                               
pkgs <- dir_ls(lib_dir)
dirs <- dir_info(pkgs, recurse = TRUE)[,1:3]                                            
setDT(dirs)
dirs <- dirs[type != "directory"]

# ==> We can see files at the root of each library take 12M in aggreagte <==
dirs[depth == 4, .(size = sum(size))]
#    size
# 1:  12M

dirs[, depth := str_count(path, "/")]
dirs[, pkg := file.path(lib_dir, str_match(path, sprintf("%s/(.*?)/.*", lib_dir))[,2L])]
dirs[depth > 4L, pkg_dir := str_match(path, sprintf("%s/(.*?)/.*", pkg))[,2L]]

# ==> The worst offenders are indeed libs, and lib is also large <==
dirs[depth > 4, .(size = sum(size)), pkg_dir][order(-size)][1:10]
#     pkg_dir    size
#  1:    libs 610.77M
#  2: include 144.18M
#  3:     doc 140.93M
#  4:     lib 104.58M
#  5:       R  91.31M
#  6:    help  61.78M
#  7:    html  51.02M
#  8:    data   25.9M
#  9:    java  11.74M
# 10:     www   8.38M
```

I then ran `strip --strip-debug` on `libs` and `lib` to reach the following

```
dirs[depth > 4, .(size = sum(size)), pkg_dir][order(-size)][1:10]
#         pkg_dir    size
#  1:     include 144.18M
#  2:         doc 140.93M
#  3:        libs  95.24M
#  4:           R  91.31M
#  5:        help  61.78M
#  6:        html  51.02M
#  7:        data   25.9M
#  8:        java  11.74M
#  9:         www   8.38M
# 10: htmlwidgets   8.24M
```

From the above example I have the following questions: `docs` seem to hold vignettes that I can access doing `browseVignettes()` I do not need this but I still require `help("stuff")` to work.

- Can I achieve this maybe using `--no-docs` or `--no-help` (I tried but running `R CMD INSTALL --no-docs --no-html xtable` still generates pdfs and html files)?
- Is there something else I can save without losing basic functionality ?

Comment: See http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/08/14/#009_compact_shared_libraries and http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/08/20/#010_stripping_shared_libraries

Comment: Damn it, I did see it in the past. That's exactly what I wanted. Feel free to answer

Answer (score 1):

Dirk EddelBuettel wrote two blog posts in 2017 that are hard to summarize here. R packages are big but it does not come from the documentation or the source code. It comes from the fact that binaries are compiled with debugging symbols. The idea is to compile the packages yourself with more specific options to get rid of useless stuff in binaries. The gain is very significant for packages with compiled code (4-5 times less space)

- http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/08/14/#009_compact_shared_libraries
- http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/08/20/#010_stripping_shared_libraries

Comment: There is even a 3rd blog post: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2019/03/27/

Comment: Interesting, it means that there is now a native solution